# WP CLI avoid 'Undefined index: HTTP_HOST' when using http_host in wp-config.php

Tags: wp-cli

I am confronted to the error `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST` when trying to use wp-cli on my wordpress install because I have this line in my wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

Bug is reported here https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/730 and there is a solution here https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/common-issues/#php-notice-undefined-index-on-_server-superglobal which is to set a default value in wp-cli context:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI && ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com';
}
```

I don't understand this solution though. Isn't the point of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` NOT to have to set a value for the current domain name? Or does this example mean that I can put ANY value for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, no matter my real domain name, as it won't be used by wp-cli?

Comment: The exclamation point `!` means "if not isset" so the default value is just ensuring that `HTTP_HOST` is defined for WP-CLI in case you don't specify `--url=...`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same configuration and error and the workaround I use to bypass the error is to always add

```
--url=mysite.com
```

at the end of the wp-cli command for a specific site. This sets the required WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL and HTTP_HOST for wp-cli to operate on so you do not need to update wp-config.php file.

For multisite's sitewide command, you may want to use

```
wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I % wp YOUR-CLI-COMMAND --url=%
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue with, in `wp-config.php`:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI && ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']   ) ) $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = '';
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI && ! isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a CLI app that bootstrapped WP that wasn't `wp-cli`.  I modified @kyodev's answer and shortened it with PHP 7.4 syntax:

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ??= '';
}
```

This works on all CLI apps, not just `wp-cli`.

Answer (score -1):

In Wordpress if you don't specify the WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL and the HTTP_HOST you get these warnings. For my website these does not prevent it of working, but I think if its giving you waring its because needed to be addressed.

These lines bellow will get these 3 variables assigned correctly and the warnings will disappear...

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'Here you need to add the server name or website name';
}

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME );
```

Hope these can fix that issue!